# Identifying the source of an upload

Tags: php, json, security

I have multiple offline MSAccess databases, from which I am generating a JSON formatted string which I am POSTing to a single online PHP script. This upload is the only contact these two separate systems have. I want to be as sure as possible that the PHP script only acts on input from valid sources (that don't have dedicated IPs). What is the most effective way of doing this?

Comment: @derp thanks, that's helpful

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be:
1) Make sure you're POSTing via SSL so at least the channel is encrypted and the step below cannot be sniffed;
2) Have some sort of "secret" key embedded in your Access data (maybe in a separate dedicated table) which the PHPscript looks out for to ensure source validity.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. My random char passphrase is currently static however, and I'm going off the assumption that this is not ideal. Maybe it's ok?

Comment: I guess it's OK as long as it's fairly long / complex and cannot be easily found out.  Without two-way communication I can't think of anything else likely to work.

Comment: I'm thinking of using a number and the date, and then - based on certain variables (date is even number, stuff like that) performing math operations with the number and date to give a semi-random result which can be replicated on either side...

Comment: Aha, some sort of time dependent hash function.  I believe that's how many online bank account two factor authentication devices work.  Again you'd need to keep your hash function as secure as the "secret" key.  And your clocks would need to be synced of course. ( and allow for POST transit time )